# Scrolling in iframe or div

Tags: css, html, scroll, scrollbar

[image]I want to have the scrollbar in Iframe So that the scrollbar always remains at the bottom.
I am developing a chat application and in the iframe a page is called which displays the chat messages,so i want it to scroll to bottom automatically.How can i do it?Thank you in advance.

```
 <div>



 <iframe id="iframeEuser2" name="iframeEuser2" src="messagedisplay.aspx" 
        style="visibility:hidden; margin-left: 0px;" 
        onload="this.style.visibility='visible';">


          </iframe>

           </div>
```

Comment: If this iframe is at the same domain you can put script with autoscroll to bottom in the page that is in your iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you give your iFrame an ID, this should work as an onLoad event

```
 document.getElementById("youriframe").contentWindow.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById("youriframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight)
```

Are you able to add an anchor to the bottom of iframed page? iFrame linked to www.yourpage.com#youranchor would do the simple trick perhaps?

Comment: No it's not working when i tried onload="document.getElementById("iframeEuser2").contentWindow.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById("iframeEuser2").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight)"

Comment: ...it still scrolls to the top